# How to setup directories in Visual Studio when using boost?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, development-environment

I have introduced boost to our code base, on my machine I created a boost directory called Thirdparty.Boost and added that as an additional include directory in my Visual Studio setting, all is fine.

However I now want to check in my changes, so the rest of the team can get them. Inorder to build the code they would need to setup boost as I have (problem number 1). In addition we have a build server, which will need changing (problem 2). I have a way of distributing boost to everyone including the build server, so that's not a problem

I need a way of referring to the boost directory without changing the default settings in Visual Studio. Why don't you change it on a project level I hear you cry? The solution has over 200 projects, which would require a lot of changes.

I just wondered if there was another way?

Cheers
Rich

Comment: As far as I understand you need to change 200 projects only once. Am I right?

Comment: VCProjects are just XML... you can simply process them with a little tool you can easily write to add the additional include path.

Comment: You can also use EnvDTE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28VS.80%29.aspx to modify the projects.

Comment: Yep, VS Macros, I didn't remember about them.

Comment: In the end I did use EnvDTE to modify the project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding an environment variable on each of your developer's machines:

```
CL=-I<...the_boost_directory...>
```

i.e. on your machine:

```
CL=-IThirdparty.Boost
```

The MS compiler adds the value of the environment variable CL to its command line, so this should do the trick for you.